# In Spring, how will we make sure the atomicity of operations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

In Spring how can we make sure that certain operations are always executed together. If any one of them fails, the entire transaction needs to be rolled back. I searched this a lot and found `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` annotations and `TransactionTemplate.execute()` methods close to my problem. Kindly clarify and help.

Comment: Are you talking about database transactions? Or what operations are you talking about. It's very difficult to help you if we do not understand what you exact problem is.

Comment: Yes(1)Both the operations are database transactions (2)One DB transaction and the other a set logical statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both @Transactional and TransactionTemplate ensure atomicity. @Transactional is for declarative transaction management, TransactionTemplate is for programmatic transaction management. You should choose one.

The idea of transaction propagation applies only to declarative transaction management and defines a transaction behaviour when it is executed in more than one method. Note that Propagation.REQUIRED is default for Transactional.propagation. It means *Support a current transaction (that is if a transaction was already started in the calling method) or create a new one if none exists*.

Answer (score 1):

**@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED**
May solve your problem.

Suppose in your Impl there is a method Excecute.Inside Excecute method there are other **M1(),M2(),M3(),M4(),M5()** methods.

May be you trying to say if for  M1(),M2().M3().M4() methods Db operation succedded and at last for M5() it throws some exception then M1() to M5() all db operation  should be rollback

```
Execute(){
M1();
M2();
M3();
M4();
M5();
```

if(Any error in any methods transaction will be roll back).As single trasaction object is used for all methods i.e(M1 to M5) when @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED is used.

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single method that delegates to the two database calls and annotate that with `@Transactional`, e.g.

```
@Transactional
public void atomicOperation(...) {
    dbCall();
    logicOperation();
}
```

If either one fails, e.g. an exception is thrown, the entire operation will rollback. The Spring Reference Documentation has dedicated a chapter for [transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), for example there is information about [@Transactional settings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) and [Transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation).